# erigi on PHP is deprecated (e-mail validation)

Tags: php, email-validation

Since `erigi()` is deprecated in PHP 5 and I am in a need to validate an e-mail id, which function should be used? I need the format for e-mail validation such as:

```
<?php
function checkEmail($email) 
{
   if(eregi("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+$]", $email)) 
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   list($Username, $Domain) = split("@",$email);

   if(getmxrr($Domain, $MXHost)) 
   {
      return TRUE;
   }
   else 
   {
      if(fsockopen($Domain, 25, $errno, $errstr, 30)) 
      {
         return TRUE; 
      }
      else 
      {
         return FALSE; 
      }
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `filter_var` PHP function instead:

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

}
```

Or, even better yet, use a [RFC-compliant email address validator.](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/) As no amount of regex will encompass all the valid emails that are possible.

Answer (score 2):

For php 5.2: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php

```
$result = filter_var($email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Or http://pl.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for any regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

En example with with filter extension.

```
<?php
function is_valid_email($email)
{
    return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false;
}

var_dump(is_valid_email('test@example.com'));
var_dump(is_valid_email('foobar'));
var_dump(is_valid_email('test+foo@example.com.com'));

[~]> php x.php 
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(true)
```

This you can then combine with further validation that you already have.